# problems moving to swf frame with javascript

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3

Further to my previous post ...and thanks so much for the responses ....
This is the real situation I'm trying to resolve.
Just need to call a swf from javascript to move the swf on to another time frame.

AS3

```
Import flash.external.ExternalInterface;

function moveOn (frame:int ) : void
{
gotoAndPlay (frame);
}
ExternalInterface.addCallback("myjsFunction", moveOn);
```

JS

```
<script language="JavaScript">
function  sendtoSwf (frame){
MyMovie.myjsFunction(frame);
}
</script>
...
<object id="MyMovie"...>
...
<param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" />
....
<embed name="MyMovie".../>
</object>
```

HTML JS trigger

```
<a href onclick=”javascript : sendtoSwf(25);”> click here </a>
```

If someone could please clarify, since I only want to trigger swf from js, do I maybe not need the ...addCallback(...) line ? Should it actually be just a ...Call(...)?
I havent quite grassped the Internal Interface idea yet.
In my html click trigger Im trying to pass an integer value which is the actual frame I want the swf to move to, I'm not sure if the trigger should link to the "sendtoSwf" function or the "myjsFunction" ...do I not need a reference in js to the actual name of the as3 function that moves the frame?(i.e. moveOn)
Any clarifacation would be GREATLY appreciated. Thanks in anticipation.
Ed

Answer (score 1):

For anyone interested this is what worked:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//checking which browser used
function getFlashMovieObject(movieName){
if (window.document[movieName]){
    return window.document[movieName];
}
if (navigator.appName.indexOf("Microsoft Internet")==-1){
    if (document.embeds && document.embeds[movieName])
        return document.embeds[movieName];
}
else{
    return document.getElementById(movieName);
}
}
//code that sends frame no to flash
function sendtoSwf(numb){
var flashMovie=getFlashMovieObject("myFlashMovie");
flashMovie.sendToFlash(numb);
}
</script>
```

And the action script

```
import flash.external.ExternalInterface;
ExternalInterface.addCallback("sendtoFlash", getFromJavaScript);
function getFromJavaScript(frame:int):void {
gotoAndPlay(frame);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You definitely need the addCallback function , but you also need to check that Javascript is ready to communicate with Actionscript. Have a look at the docs, the example is fairly detailed and should give you the information you need.

check the External Interface class
http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/

Comment: Thanks Patrick
I managed to get it working. Added some code to check for browser type and re-worked the code.